# Break into debugger and stop execution on the first instruction each time JavaScript code execution starts

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I'm debugging a webpage's JavaScript code.

**I need to break into debugger and stop execution on the first instruction each time JavaScript code execution starts** (the most common case is a event that triggers a callback function).

Of course I'd prefer avoid placing a breakpoint or `debugger;` at the beginning of every callback (they're many).

I can't find a way to do it with the developer tools of Safari and Firefox (but maybe I'm missing something...)

Is it possible to do it programmatically?

I'm using jQuery to bind events to callbacks. So a partial solution that stops execution when a callback set with jQuery is executed would be good for me.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4b85hkjv/2/ ?

Comment: You could use a global boolean in your code, which you can check on with an IF statement. If it's true (first time) do `debugger;` and set the boolean to false, So it will not be called multiple times.

Comment: another option http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4b85hkjv/3/

Comment: @ArunPJohny the first fiddle is the one that gets closer to what I asked but I'd have to put `debugger;` into the overrided `jQuery.event.dispatch` and then, when the execution stops there, step over/into through the jQuery code until I reach the callback... it's a little awkward but it works. Thank you.

Comment: @David unfortunately I'm working on some code I inherited and there are a lot of callbacks all around. Of course I can do what you suggest but I'm looking for a "global" solution to avoid spotting every callback.